# is that possible to work out a custom authentication and authorization mechanism that still utilizes <security-constraint> in web.xm

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'd like a custom authentication and authorization solution which is different to BASIC or FORM methods. Actually it is like a enhanced version of j_security_check.
In the mean time, I like my solution to use the standard  settings such as URL patterns, names, and roles.

Is that possible by using Servlet filters? Or can I "extend" j_security_check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used [AuthenticRoast](http://code.google.com/p/authenticroast/) once for a project. It implements a JSR-196 authentication provider using an custom authentication/authorization provider.

Otherwise you have to completely implement a JSR-196 a JAAS module

Comment: I've decided to go for Spring Security as it is highly configurable and has built-in login functionality ready to use.

Comment: Ok, I thought you wanted a standard solution using default J2EE patterns, names, roles, etc. But Spring Secutiy is also a good option.